# Sort list of maps based on multiple keys

Tags: java, arraylist, groovy, mule, dataweave

I have a `List` of `Map`s which looks like this :

```
[{type=UNL,date=20170606,publication=ECC,boNumber=34,value=500}
{type=UNP,date=20190807,publication=ECD,boNumber=24,value=100}
{type=UNA,date=20170606,publication=ECC,boNumber=34,value=400}
{type=UNC,date=20170606,publication=ECC,boNumber=34,value=300}
{type=UNF,date=20190807,publication=ECD,boNumber=24,value=200}]
```

The most important fields for me are values of  `date,publication,boNumber` for example `20170606 ECC 34`. I want to sort this `List` using these three fields to be together.

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
[{type=UNL,date=20170606,publication=ECC,boNumber=34,value=500}
{type=UNA,date=20170606,publication=ECC,boNumber=34,value=400}
{type=UNC,date=20170606,publication=ECC,boNumber=34,value=300}
{type=UNP,date=20190807,publication=ECD,boNumber=24,value=100}
{type=UNF,date=20190807,publication=ECD,boNumber=24,value=200}]
```

How can this be implemented in mule, using groovy, dataweave or Java.

Comment: Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Comment: "Best" in which way? it is really not clear what you expect us to do here. Your question is too broad and unspecific. Hint: try yourself - and when you run into problems, put up *your* code and we help from there.

Comment: @GhostCat why is "how do I sort a list of maps using multiple keys of the map" not a proper question? It is not really broad and unspecific. Or do you just don't like the phrase "best approach"?

Comment: @Vampire Because of that "the best way" term? That opens room for endless discussions. There are many different dimension in which a solution could be best ... or not so good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Dataweave to achieve this

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload orderBy ($.date ++ $.publication ++ $.boNumber)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

What you are after is `.sort { [it.date, it.publication, it.boNumber] }`.

```
def listOfMaps = [[type:'UNL',date:20170606,publication:'ECC',boNumber:34,value:500],
[type:'UNP',date:20190807,publication:'ECD',boNumber:24,value:100],
[type:'UNA',date:20170606,publication:'ECC',boNumber:34,value:400],
[type:'UNC',date:20170606,publication:'ECC',boNumber:34,value:300],
[type:'UNF',date:20190807,publication:'ECD',boNumber:24,value:200]]

listOfMaps
    .each { println it }
println()
listOfMaps
    .sort { [it.date, it.publication, it.boNumber] }
    .each { println it }
```

for example outputs

```
[type:UNL, date:20170606, publication:ECC, boNumber:34, value:500]
[type:UNP, date:20190807, publication:ECD, boNumber:24, value:100]
[type:UNA, date:20170606, publication:ECC, boNumber:34, value:400]
[type:UNC, date:20170606, publication:ECC, boNumber:34, value:300]
[type:UNF, date:20190807, publication:ECD, boNumber:24, value:200]

[type:UNL, date:20170606, publication:ECC, boNumber:34, value:500]
[type:UNA, date:20170606, publication:ECC, boNumber:34, value:400]
[type:UNC, date:20170606, publication:ECC, boNumber:34, value:300]
[type:UNP, date:20190807, publication:ECD, boNumber:24, value:100]
[type:UNF, date:20190807, publication:ECD, boNumber:24, value:200]
```

Comment: Your solution produces different result when `date` is not an Integer - https://gist.github.com/wololock/16a895091e359ecff05a38df96515758 This field looks more like a date String with format `yyyyMMdd`

Comment: @SzymonStepniak well, actually the requirement was only that the elements with matching `date`, `publication` and `boNumber` are together in the resulting list.

Comment: That's correct, but it doesn't change the fact, that your solution produces non-deterministic results. It only proves that there is something wrong with your code - `Integer` and its `String` representation should sort in the same way.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak well, what is "wrong" is, that sort of the groups against each other is random, as lists are compared and no explicit sorting is defined. But it fully satisfies the requirement that the lines should be together. Noone asked for reproducible sorting.

Comment: @Vampire what does passing the list into sort actually means? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @tvelykyy as you can see at http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.7/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#sort(groovy.lang.Closure), if the closure you give it has one argument (the implcit `it` in this case), you specify the comparison criterion. This means that the maps where all three elements are the same, are sorted together.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Groovy would look like this:

```
List list = [[type: 'UNL', date: '20170606', publication: 'ECC', boNumber: 34, value: 500],
             [type: 'UNP', date: '20190807', publication: 'ECD', boNumber: 24, value: 100],
             [type: 'UNA', date: '20170606', publication: 'ECC', boNumber: 34, value: 400],
             [type: 'UNC', date: '20170606', publication: 'ECC', boNumber: 34, value: 300],
             [type: 'UNF', date: '20190807', publication: 'ECD', boNumber: 24, value: 200]]

List sorted = list.sort { a,b ->
    a.date == b.date ?
            (a.publication == b.publication ?
                    a.boNumber <=> b.boNumber :
                    a.publication <=> b.publication) :
            a.date <=> b.date
}

sorted.each { println it }
```

Closure passed to `.sort()` method does following:

- firstly it sorts by `date` field
- then if both dates are equal it checks if `publication` fields are equal
- then if both `publication` fields are equal it sorts by `boNumber`
- otherwise it sorts by `publication`

#### Output

```
[type:UNL, date:20170606, publication:ECC, boNumber:34, value:500]
[type:UNA, date:20170606, publication:ECC, boNumber:34, value:400]
[type:UNC, date:20170606, publication:ECC, boNumber:34, value:300]
[type:UNP, date:20190807, publication:ECD, boNumber:24, value:100]
[type:UNF, date:20190807, publication:ECD, boNumber:24, value:200]
```

Comment: Just curious, do you think your solution is better than just extracting a sort-key with the three fields like in my solution?

Comment: @Vampire I wouldn't say it's better. Your solution produces correct result only if `date` field is an Integer. If you replace Integers with String (`date` field looks like a one that holds `yyyyMMdd` date string) then your solution is broken - https://gist.github.com/wololock/16a895091e359ecff05a38df96515758